# Crashes and exceptions are not logged in Google analytics in Titanium

Tags: titanium-mobile

I have used the following code to track the crashes in the application in titanium

GA.trackUncaughtExceptions = true;

But the crashes are not logged in google analytics dashboard.

Comment: I don't see any reference to crash logging in the GA module api doc. But, I don't have the module installed at the moment. In the meantime, you may want to check crittercism.

Comment: I'm assuming that you are using a module you downloaded from the Marketplace, since Titanium doesn't have support for GA out of the box. I suggest writing the developer of the module for support.

Comment: Yes, I have used the module from from Marketplace and I have left a question there but I haven't receive any reply.